# timmolter/XChange - Cryptsy GetFee

Tags: java, json, bitcoin

I know it may be an obscure api but does anyone have an idea as to how I can get the fee for a market?

I tried this

```
system.out.println("\nCalculateFees:\n"
                + ((CryptsyTradeServiceRaw) TradeService).calculateCryptsyFees(CryptsyOrderType.Sell, new BigDecimal("2"), new BigDecimal("286.62403820")));
```

and it gives me the wrong fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like cryptsy posts their fees here: [Fees](https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/fees)

```
if(VolumeInBTC < 0.5){
            PairFee = 0.0033; //0.33%
        }
        else if(VolumeInBTC >= 0.5 && VolumeInBTC < 1.0){
            PairFee = 0.0031; //0.31%
        }
        else if(VolumeInBTC >= 1.0 && VolumeInBTC < 5.0){
            PairFee = 0.0029; //0.29%
        }
        else if(VolumeInBTC >= 5 && VolumeInBTC < 20){
            PairFee = 0.0027; //0.27%
        }
        else if(VolumeInBTC >= 20){
            PairFee = 0.0025; //0.25%
        }
        else{
            System.exit(1);//something went wrong
        }
        return PairFee;
    }
```